# Google Cloud Datastore and Flask App Engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

How do I access entities defined in Google Cloud Datastore in my Flask App running on Google App Engine.

Are there any code samples ?

I know there is a walkthrough with python script to get it working from a VM. [walkthrough](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_python/). However, I am looking for getting this working in Google App-Engine.

Comment: I have much _better_ one here: https://github.com/gae-init/gae-init

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I wrote sample app few months back, it would help you:

https://github.com/rajendrakrp/Flask-Gae-Init

Comment: See this also: https://github.com/rajendrakrp/GAE-Flask-OpenID. Look into models.py, it uses `db`(now ndb) to create models in datastore.

Comment: I am looking for authentication code that comes before "import googledatastore as datastore"

Comment: Initial you haven't mentioned `walkthrough`. My app just gives you the platform to work on GAE with Flask. I suggest first try out this, then go for complex stuffs.

Comment: I appreciate that. I already have my app running on GAE with Flask, therefore your recommendation is redundant

Comment: If you are running on App Engine, you can use `db` or `ndb` to talk to your app's Datastore (as in rajpy's example). The `googledatastore` library (https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_python) is designed for talking to your Datastore from other environments such as Google Compute Engine.

Comment: FYI: The sample doesn't hashout the usage of models/datastore, it just has an empty file placeholder....

Answer (score 0):

The [Google App Engine Python 3 Quickstart documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app) features a [Flask](http://flask.palletsprojects.com) app using [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore) that users following the tutorial build one step-at-a-time. Here is [the page which specifically discusses its use](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/storing-and-retrieving-data) in the app (step 3). If you don't want to read docs, you can go straight to [the quickstart code repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard_python3/building-an-app). (If you're a Python 2 user, there's no difference in its use [other than your 2.x-3.x diffs].)